# Layout problems in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, screen, resolution

I made an app, this app has all the layouts sizes
(layout, layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge, well except for the xxlarge)
An the problem is that I have published the app, and the lay outs look just fine in the
android studio, but when I download the app with my 7 inches tablet, it looks messy, is not as
well-arranged as in the layout, Why?

Comment: It seems you failed reading the `tablet support` documentation.

Comment: please provide screenshots of expected and real layout

Answer (score 0):

U should not give constant width and height in your xml file. It should be either wrapcontent or fillparent. So that it will take according to the screen resolution.

Comment: Great, wrap_content will do, but the buttons and other objects will be smaller and hard to re-size them, how to solve this?